# Pixelated border as an android style xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, svg

I am trying to create a theme/style for my buttons in my android layout. I want to create a style where the corners are curved but are also pixelated (To fit the theme of my app) but also respects the text inside by keeping the text inside its borders.

I was able to create this type of pixelated border in javascript/css.

```css
.pixelated {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: black;
    border-image-slice: 4;
    border-image-width: 2;
    border-image-outset: 0;
    border-image-source: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27%20width%3D%2712%27%20height%3D%2712%27%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%27M2%202h2v2H2zM4%200h2v2H4zM10%204h2v2h-2zM0%204h2v2H0zM6%200h2v2H6zM8%202h2v2H8zM8%208h2v2H8zM6%2010h2v2H6zM0%206h2v2H0zM10%206h2v2h-2zM4%2010h2v2H4zM2%208h2v2H2z%27%20fill%3D%27%23000%27%20%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
    // The SVG:
    // <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='12' height='12'>
    //   <path d='M2 2h2v2H2zM4 0h2v2H4zM10 4h2v2h-2zM0 4h2v2H0zM6 0h2v2H6zM8 2h2v2H8zM8 8h2v2H8zM6 10h2v2H6zM0 6h2v2H0zM10 6h2v2h-2zM4 10h2v2H4zM2 8h2v2H2z' fill='#000' />
    // </svg>
}
```

```html
<div class="pixelated">A Button</div>
<div class="pixelated">A Longer Button</div>
<div class="pixelated">An Even Longer Button</div>
```

I was wondering if its possible to recreate something similar to this javascript/css as an xml style/theme to be used in an android layout. If this cant be re-created as an android style, could this be made programmatically with java?

Thank you!

Comment: not sure how you'd create this with xml, but perhaps you can create this type of border as an svg and then just use that as a border for your buttons

Comment: @a_local_nobody border-image-source in the css is just a small svg which is why I commented below it. How would I go about using that? I can convert the svg to a an Vector asset thanks to Android Studio, but how would I use it as a border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has an equivalent to those sort of CSS borders.

They are called [NinePatch images](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch).

You should be able to convert them easily enough.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know NinePatch images existed. I was able to use them to achieve a similar button style.